# Question on closure of intersection os sets

Tags: general-topology

I know that in general $cl(A \cap B) \subset cl(A) \cap cl(B)$. 
When is it true that $cl(A\cap B) = cl(A)\cap cl(B)$?

Comment: I think, when the intersection is closed in $A$ and in $B$.

Comment: @ThorbenKastenholz : I do not think this is enough. Consider the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ThorbenKastenholz You mean when $A \cap B$ is a closed set in A and in B?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch yes you are right. I didn't put much thought into my assumption

Comment: If $A \subset B$, then $A \cap B = A$, $cl(A\cap B ) = cl(A)$ and $cl(A) \subset cl(B)$. So $cl(A) \cap cl(B) \subset cl(A\cap B)$, and then $cl(A \cap B) =cl(A) \cap cl(B)$. Is this correct? Are there other conditions under which it's true?

Comment: It feels intuitively (to me :p) as it would be true if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$...?

Comment: @user202542: Not necessarily. Take $A=[0,1)$ and $B=\{0\}\cup(1,2)$ in $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology; then $A\cap B=\{0\}\ne\varnothing$, $\operatorname{cl}(A\cap B)=\{0\}$, and $(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott A great example, thank you! Can you think of any other condition that would make it true?

Comment: @user202542: Nothing that isn’t basically just a restatement of the desired result.